# Dropping SQL Tables if they exist / Creating if they don't (Within C#)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a C# Method to DROP tables if they exist and to create if they do not.

So far I have created a SQL query which is TRYING to delete the tables if they exist.

However I am getting this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'.

This is my code

```
        static void CheckTablesExist()
        {
            try
            {
                // Build connection string
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    DataSource = "WIN10-LAP-HJP",
                    UserID = "sa",
                    Password = "Mypassword123",
                    InitialCatalog = "SAPExtract"
                };

                // Connect to SQL
                Console.Write("Connecting to SQL Server ... ");
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Checking If table dbo.FolderInfo");

                    string queryCheckTable = "if object_id(@FolderTable, @FileTable) NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.FolderInfo ";

                   // string queryCheckTable = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS @FolderTable";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryCheckTable, connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add("@FolderTable", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "dbo.FolderInfo";
                        command.Parameters.Add("@FileTable", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "dbo.FileInfo";

                        connection.Open();

                        var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        // Check Error


                    }
                }
            }

            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have several issues going on here. dbo.FileType is not a type. FileType might a type but the schema is not the type name. You also have NVarChar parameters but you don't specify the size. It will use the default size and I don't recall off the top of my head what that size is for pass through queries from dotnet. But I also am a bit confused why you pass the table name to check as a parameter but then hard code the table name to drop. I realize you can't parameterize the drop but why bother with parameters to only sort of use them?

Comment: Database structural operations are better done and handled by stored procedures.

Comment: Just FYI: you can simplify it  -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverstorageengine/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving the syntax error because you are missing the word IS before NOT NULL.  The following SQL should work:

```
if object_id(@FolderTable, @FileTable) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.FolderInfo
```